# for loop answer won't stop repeating

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have this program:

```
print('~Find and Replace~\n')

phrase = input('Enter a phrase:')
find = input('Enter a letter to find:')
end = input('Enter a letter to replace:')

for j in phrase:
    j = phrase.count(find)
    print(j)
```

and it came out like this:

```
~Find and Replace~

Enter a phrase:pythop
Enter a letter to find:p
Enter a letter to replace:x
2
2
2
2
2
2
```

what should I do to make it print only once with the for loop?

Answer (score 5):

Just get rid of the `for` loop. Why do you have it? (What are you trying to repeat?)

```
print('~Find and Replace~\n')

phrase = input('Enter a phrase:')
find = input('Enter a letter to find:')
end = input('Enter a letter to replace:')

j = phrase.count(find)
print(j)
```

Comment: I suspect the goal is to count and replace on a per-word basis (since the prompt is for a phrase, even if they only provide one word), but yeah, the question is not clear, and they made no effort to split from a string to a list of words.

Comment: I'd suspect OP wants to loop accordingly to the letter count, as ShadowRanger has also suggested this is one possibility.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to replace letters in a string, then use the [`str.replace()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace) function. There is no need for a for-loop.

```
phrase = input('Enter a phrase:')
find = input('Enter a letter to find:')
end = input('Enter a letter to replace:')

print(phrase.replace(find, end))
```